# git clone into home directory

Tags: linux, git, home-directory

```
$ git clone ssh://host/repo.git ~/
destination directory '/home/username/' already exists.
```

Can anyone tell me how to make this work? I'm trying to quickly be able to replicate common dev scripts and config.

Comment: `git clone` looks to either create a new directory under the working path, or at the path specified. Since `~/` already exists, it can't create a new dir...

Comment: Do you actually want to pull your whole home directory from a git repo? Or into a subdirectory?

Comment: Yes, all the files in the repo belong in the home directory.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
cd ~
git init
git remote add origin ssh://host/repo.git
git pull origin master
```

Answer (score 2):

The clone command creates a new directory when you pass a second argument:

```
$ git clone ssh://host/repo.git ~/your_directory
```

`clone` will create `~/your_directory`. If the directory already exists it will give you the error you get.

Comment: @rich just give a directory name like in my example or do `cd ~ && git clone ssh://host/repo.git`

Answer (score 1):

```
cd ~
git clone ssh://host/repo.git
```

After that, you have the project in the `/home/username/repo/` directory

If you want to have the project in a different folder name (e.g 'foo/')

```
mkdir ~/foo
cd ~/foo
git clone ssh://host/repo.git foo/
```

Comment: I want it checked out in the home directory though.

Answer (score -1):

I would clone the repository into a subdirectory:

```
git clone ssh://your/git/repo.git ~/repo
```

And create symlinks to the configuration files:

```
ln -s ~/repo/.bashrc ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: That would be a nightmare to do for each and every file in the repo for every machine I want to clone it onto.

Comment: Of course, but you create a shell script for that aswell.. [Github example](https://github.com/Mytho/dotfiles/blob/master/setup.sh)